# SCIP: setting absolute tolerance

Tags: scip

I'd like to ask SCIP to solve a problem to within a specified absolute tolerance, ie, it should quit as soon as the difference between the upper and lower bound is small enough. What's the parameter that controls this tolerance?

Oddly enough, I've been unable to find it by perusing the list of [all SCIP parameters](http://scip.zib.de/doc-2.0.2/html/PARAMETERS.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here they are:

```
# solving stops, if the relative gap = |(primalbound - dualbound)/dualbound| is below the given value
# [type: real, range: [0,1.79769313486232e+308], default: 0]
limits/gap = 0

# solving stops, if the absolute gap = |primalbound - dualbound| is below the given value
# [type: real, range: [0,1.79769313486232e+308], default: 0]
limits/absgap = 0
```

"tolerance" usually refers to the allowed violation of the computed solution, i.e. the amount of allowed infeasibility. Apparently, you were looking for the "gap limit".